# Extending "typing" status till bot's reply

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dispatcher.message()
async def telebot(message: types.Message):
    global reference
    await bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=message.chat.id, action=telegram.constants.ChatAction.TYPING)

    print(f">>> USER: \n\t{message.text}")

    reference.messages.append(message.text)

    response = palm.chat(messages=reference.messages).reply(message.text)

    reference.response = str(response.last)
    print(f">>> Answer: \n\t{reference.response}")
    await message.answer(reference.response)
```

In the above code the typing status is visible for only few seconds, what should be done to modify the code to extend the typing status till the bot responds?